# Referenced symbol not found

Tags: c++, solaris

I am trying to run a program preloading my library using `LD_PRELOAD`. At runtime the program is throwing following error.

> ld.so.1: gdbser64: fatal: relocation error: file  libmy.so: symbol
>   _ZN10__cxxabiv118register_exit_codeEPFYvvE: referenced symbol not found

`libmy.so` is not using `register_exit_code` symbol anywhere. It might be case that a standard library linked by libmy.so is using the function. But I am not able to find who is using this symbol or who has defined it.

It is on `Solaris`, compiled using `CC(solaris cpp compiler)`.

Comment: if solaris uses also elf file format, you can search with objdump for undefined symbols to get an idea which file requires the symbol. And naturally you can search also for files which provide them...

Comment: It could be possible that program or executable file which is dynamically linked to libmy.so expects symbol `register_exit_code` in libmy.so shared-lib. So its most probably issue with executable or shared-lib which depend on libmy.so.

Comment: @Klaus objdump is showing the symbol as undefined but not the file/library in which it is defined/called. I have used 'objdump -t libmy.so'.

Comment: Yes, but you have linked your libmy.so so you know from which files your product derives. If you search in the source libs, you will find the user I believe.

Comment: @PravarJawalekar *So its most probably issue with executable or shared-lib which depend on libmy.so.* Not if the executable that fails to run under LD_PRELOAD can run without LD_PRELOAD set. If it does run without `LD_PRELOAD`, the problem is with the library or the `LD_PRELOAD` value. We need the output from `ldd libmy.so`. It looks like preloading a C++ library into an executable with no dependency on any C++ runtime.

Comment: Which version of CC are you using for the lib and application? Also what are the complier/linker options (in particular those related to the language standard and C++ runtime/std libs)?

Comment: @PaulFloyd Compiler options are: CPPFLAGS =  -fno-strict-aliasing -O2  -fPIC -lstdc++ -std=c++0x -g -z record. CC version is  Sun C++ 5.13 SunOS_i386 2014/10/20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all your source files/libs built with -std=c++0x?

Otherwise, the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37071/gndfg.html) suggest that if you are linking with -lstdc++ then you should use `-lstdc++ -lgcc_s -lCrunG3`

Comment: I have observed, on Solaris, g++ compiled binary works well with g++ compiled libraries and not with gcc, CC compiled libraries. Is this correct? Why is so?

Comment: In general, you can mix objects compiled with different C compilers but not with different C++ compilers. The reason is that there is no standard binary interface (ABI) in C++ except for some platforms like Itanium. In particular the C++ runtime library (which defines things like how exceptions are handled) is usually different and incompatible.